# Asymptotic expansion of $\int_{ [-T, T]^2} f(x-y) dxdy$ as $T\to\infty$

Tags: integration, asymptotics

For a function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ and a constant $T>0$, consider the integral
$$I(T) = \int_{-T}^T \int_{-T}^T f(x-y) dxdy,$$
where $f$ is a decaying function so that the Riemann improper integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f$$
is well-defined. I am interested in the $T\to\infty$ asymptotic behavior of $I(T)$.

**What I try**: Heuristically, the transformation $X = (x+y)/2$ and $Y = x-y$ gives
$$I(T) = \int_R f(Y) dXdY,$$
where $R$ is the transformed region. One may approximate by replacing $R$ to the region $(X,Y)\in [-T, T]\times \mathbb R$:
$$I(T) \approx \int_{-T}^T dX \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(Y) dXDY = 2T \int_{-\infty}^\infty f .$$

However, if $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f=0$, the problem of estimating $I(T)$ is harder. One concrete example for this case is
$$f(x) = \frac{e^{ix}}{(x+ia)^\alpha},$$
where $\alpha>0$ and $a>0$. (We have $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f=0$ by the contour integration.) In this case, what is the asymptotic behavior of $I(T)$?

**Question**: What is the asymptotic behavior of
$$I(T) = \int_{-T}^T \int_{-T}^T \frac{e^{i(x-y)}}{(x-y+ia)^\alpha}dxdy, \quad T\to\infty \:?$$
(If needed, one may simplify and set $a \to 0^+$.)